# Mysql select query with multiple id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Well, I've a Mysql table(**oc_calendar**) like this:

```
id      start_date         username
1       2013-04-04         18
2       2013-03-31         19
3       2013-04-04         19
4       2013-04-02         19 
5       2013-04-03         18
```

With following query I can get all id based on search result:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT username FROM oc_calendar WHERE start_date 
between '$from' AND '$to'");

while($re_search = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {

$search_p_id = $re_search['username']; // here is the result Like: 18, 19 etc..
}
```

Now I'm trying to get another table(**property_step1**) information based on variable **$search_p_id** with following query but It's show error. May be my query is not correct.

**Note: Variable $search_p_id can be 18 or 19, 18 etc..**

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step1 WHERE propertyid IN (" . 
implode(',', $search_p_id) . ")");
```

Why it's show the error message, Any Idea ?

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Comment: You should say what error you're getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for two queries, you can do this with only one query, by [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)ing the two tables:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM oc_calendar AS o
INNER JOIN  property_step1 AS p ON o.username = p.propertyid
WHERE o.start_date between '$from' AND '$to';
```

I assumed the join condition: `o.username = p.propertyid` since you get the list of `username` values from the first table then select all the rows from the second value where the `propertyid` in the list of `username` values selected from the first table using the `IN` predicate. So, I used `JOIN` it is like the predicate `IN` but it is safer, and let you select columns from both tables.

---

**Note that:** Please ***Stop*** using the `Mysql_`* extensions, your code this way is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), it is also deprecated. Use [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `implode()` to non array data. you shoul change the value of `$search_p_id` value as array.

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT username FROM oc_calendar WHERE start_date between '$from' AND '$to'");
$search_p_id = array();

while($re_search = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
    $search_p_id []= $re_search['username']; // here is the result Like: 18, 19 etc..
}

$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step1 WHERE propertyid IN (" . implode(',', $search_p_id) . ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$search_p_id` currently is not an array, so `implode(',', $search_p_id)` is most likely failing.

change how you set `$search_p_id`

```
while($re_search = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
  $search_p_id[] = $re_search['username']; // here is the result Like: 18, 19 etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're firstly using deprecate mysql api, switch to pdo as Mahmoud says.

Secondly you're using the implode function on $search_p_id on a non array which can perhaps give you undesirable result.  Try the following instead:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT username FROM oc_calendar WHERE start_date 
between '$from' AND '$to'");
$search_p_id = array();
while($re_search = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
   array_push($search_p_id, $re_search['username']);
}   

search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step1 WHERE propertyid IN (" . 
implode(',', $search_p_id) . ")");
```